# PHP infinite loop is stopping on first minute of every hour

Tags: php, infinite-loop

Any idea why a simple infinite loop stops on the very first minute of every hour? For instance, 21:01, 22:01, 23:01, etc.

The server is running Ubuntu 12.04 and the PHP script is launched using command: "php -f test.php"

```
while (1 == 1) {
    echo "test";
    sleep(30);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:** It doesn't matter whether I run the script 16:05 or 16:49, it will stop on 17:01, so the issue is not related to the *set_time_limit* value.

**UPDATE:** If the script has to sleep for an hour and then echo "test", the "test" will not be echoed. The script stops it's work without finishing the loop itself.

**UPDATE:** It seems that I've found out what's killing the script. I've set the PHP script to report All errors and right before the *:01 time comes up, I get the text: *Terminated*. I've Googled that the script might get *Terminated* by OOM killer and, unfortunately, I don't have permission to change it's settings on my current VPS. I'm switching to VDS and will try to modify OOM killer settings.

Comment: 1st - check if PHP has set timeout, 2nd check if your ubuntu has something set to clear tasks which are running too long and etc..

Do you run this inside your terminal or its on crontab task ?

Comment: @Svetlio I'm running it in Terminal. The PHP doesn't have any timeout. The script simply stops, it doesn't matter if I launch it on the 59th or 15th minute, it stops on the next hour first minute.

Comment: @Synaps My pattern is to simply run this script every 30 seconds without stopping it by any means

Comment: As @Svetlio already mentioned: There will be some cron(tab) system task that cleans your processes. Look for crons running each hour. Whats happened when you restart your server. Still at *:01 when the jobs get killed? So then have a look for cron tasks running at *:01.

Comment: @TomFreudenberg There's no cron job that is Terminating my PHP process. After system reboot the same thing happens, right at *:01. I've also tried rewriting the OS from 12.04 to 14.04 - same thing.

Comment: @tomtam it is possible that your ssh session has timeout.. 
Try instead of making echo to log this text in the loop and put it inside your crontab (you can log the time instead this test text). (but set it to run just once not each minute to start new task and make some limit lets say 360 times with this sleep 30 will make 3 hour looping) ..

Comment: @tomtam I am not sure through your other comments if this issue still exists? But let me say to all other answers: If it should be a timeout problem, that would happened always timed after start not allways at *:01 on each hour. Even not after a reboot. So if there is still this issue whenever you start that script and it gets stopped at *:01 there must be some kind of watchdog process. Are you maybe influenced by a root kit or something like this?

Comment: If possible do the start from your console or create a session by `screen` (apt-get install screen) to make sure that not your connection brings up that issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php file through apache i.e. as a URL then  you should do

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //0=NOLIMIT
```

If you are running through CLI this should not be happening generally

UPDATE
Below are few Notes form [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php). I hope it will help you

> **Warning** This function has no effect when PHP is running in safe mode.
>   There is no workaround other than turning off safe mode or changing
>   the time limit in the php.ini.
>
> **Note:** The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive
>   max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script
>   itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution
>   of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations,
>   database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum
>   time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows
>   where the measured time is real.

So, it is possible that PHP code doesn't actually breaks. But, any other conenction/call is getting broken.

Comment: I'm using this with CLI and the parameter "max_execution_time" is set to 0. It's strange since it was working fine until now and I haven't changed neither the script nor the settings.

Comment: If running from CLI this param has not influence as I know.

Comment: I just read the manual for set_time_limit(), If the issue occurs by execution timeout, there must be an error printed out at console like: timeout limit. But I understand ... there is no message ... just like kill -9 your-process-id?

Comment: So, it is possible that PHP code doesn't actually breaks. But, any other conenction/call is getting broken.

Answer (score 0):

i guess it's because of [Limits the maximum execution time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) on php .

if you want repeat a script every day , hour and minute you should use [Cronjob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to call your script every time you need.

cronjob available in popular web hosts like direct admin and cpanel

for example you can use below command for run your script every one minute

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/script.php
```

if you want run script every second you can set maximum execution to one minute and repeat a code every second in it and use cronjob to call it every minute

Comment: I want the script to be running continuously. And since the script stops on the first minute of every hour, the issue is not related to set_time_limit.

Comment: @tomtam i say you can use cronjob to running continuously your script , if your script can run 1 minute you can call it every minute with cronjob ... it's min your script continuously is running

Comment: This is a possible option but it will not resolve that issue. The question on @tomtam is why the process is stopped every hour at *:01

Answer (score 0):

On my ubuntu system there is a script in `/etc/cron.d/php5`

```
# /etc/cron.d/php5: crontab fragment for php5
#  This purges session files older than X, where X is defined in seconds
#  as the largest value of session.gc_maxlifetime from all your php.ini
#  files, or 24 minutes if not defined.  See /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime

# Look for and purge old sessions every 30 minutes
09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime)
```

That script `/usr/lib/php5/maxliftime` will check for param

```
session.gc_maxlifetime
```

in any `php.ini` file located at `/etc/php5/*/php.ini`

Check for that value via

```
cd /etc/php5
grep -ri gc_maxlifetime .
```

If there is a value 3600 you should got it.

Comment: Hm ... looking on another server from us, the `sessionclean` script will only drop files in /var/lib/php5 ... not sure if this depends on Ubuntu version. So maybe the above will help, maybe not - Looking forward to your results